# Using HttpClient to upload stream portions one at a time?

Tags: c#, .net, dotnet-httpclient

Is there any easy way to use HttpClient and upload stream portions?
For example, open a file, set the starting point of the stream and tell how much content should be read from that point.

Comment: absolutely, yes. the term used for this is "chunking". show the code you have, point us to any problems you have with getting it to work, and somebody may be able to help.

Comment: I'm not talking about chunking in that way. I'm talking about, for example, opening a file of 10MB and sending the content from offset +1MB and length 1MB. Ideally I would expect System.Net.Http.StreamContent to allow specifying offset and length of the stream.

Comment: for offset, use the `Seek` function on the stream you're reading from. For length limitation, I would subclass the `FileStream`, or use a `PushStreamContent` that limits the number of bytes to transmit inside its closure.

Comment: Came to the same conclusions, but got tricked by a backend bug that made me think the subclassing did not work. Eventually I opted for PushStreamContent as it is not difficult to extract that part of code only, from the WebApi source.